# Mapping point data from excel spreadsheet

Tags: flex

I follow your blogs and love your posts. For the past couple of weeks I have been using http://gisonline.dep.wv.gov/xls/index.html to plot data points from excel files. But for some reason it is not working anymore. I really find this file very useful and would love it if you can tell me why its not working anymore. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Please consult our FAQ and the advice it provides about how to ask an answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're referring to QGIS or ArcGIS but there is a very useful ESRI resource [here](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0312/importing-data-from-excel-spreadsheets.html) which you might find helpful in absence of the above.